# Create new C library in lua

Tags: lua, embedded, lua-5.2, lua-api

I want to know how i can create and use a new C library in lua 5.2.3. I can't use dynamic library (require, shared library, ...) due to I am on an embedded system. I found an answer but it is for lua 5.0 (http://www.lua.org/pil/26.2.html) and so it is not compatible. If someone have a idea ?

Comment: Just write it like you had shared-objects, but link it with the lua base and provide the setup-function to the base system in the lua-config-file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit [`linit.c`](http://www.lua.org/source/5.2/linit.c.html) and add your library entry point to it. Then add the modified `linit.c` to your project. The linker will use your copy instead of the one in the Lua library.

This assumes your app calls `luaL_openlibs`.

Comment: I have one more problem. I make a script lua in which I call one of the function from my new library. I think I need to add a link between the script and the lua source like a require. But I have no idea, require seems not the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Lua 5.2 has some API changes over 5.1/5.0 -- so use the [reference for 5.2.3 instead](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html). You can also buy [Programming in Lua 3rd edition](http://www.lua.org/pil/#3ed) for 5.2, which has updated examples.