# Called function from a new library

Tags: lua, embedded, lua-5.2

I make a script lua in which I call one of the function from my new library. The library is declared in linit.c because I am on an embedded system. ([Create new C library in lua](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25311192/create-new-c-library-in-lua)). I think I need to add a link between the script and the lua source like a require. But I have no idea, require seems not the answer.

Comment: Is this the sort of thing you are looking for? http://www.rasterbar.com/products/luabind.html

Comment: Not really. I just want to know how i can use loadedlibs structure from linit.c in lua 5.2.3. Because I add my new library in this struture.