# Building a custom, portable Lua binary

Tags: lua, windows-7

I need to create a Lua binary for Windows that is fully portable, meaning that I can have it on a flash drive and it will work on any Windows computer (well, Windows 7 computer). I need at least a few additional libraries including Lua socket, a library that allows the proper storage (without rounding at all) and computation of large numbers (around 81 digits in total), and the rs232 library.

The problem is that I don't know how to compile them together into a binary, or if I can use some method to just use a plain Lua binary and use require to add the others. I've been researching this for a long time (a few weeks now) and haven't been able to find a solution. If anyone can help, it would be greatly appreciated.

If it makes the process any easier, I do have a Linux operating system I can use if necessary.

Comment: Do you have dll files for all your libraries?

Comment: I have a dll file for Lua socket, but using require("socket") gave me an error about an invalid character. Other than that, no, but I can try to find them.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25311192/create-new-c-library-in-lua.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: if you are using Windows, you can get the .dll files for each library and add them to your Lua directory. I now have a version of Lua with all of the libraries I wanted, plus a few more. Thank you everyone for your help.